# Multivariable form of Hensel's Lemma

Tags: number-theory, multivariable-calculus

I'm attempting to find integers $x,y,z$ such that $F(x,y,z)\equiv 0 (\mod 13^2)$ where $F$ is a given quadratic function in three variables. I was wondering if there is a form of Hensel's lemma for functions of this type? Thanks.